# Как сохранить данные объекта-коллекции в кастомном типе doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine2

В общем есть сущность, в ней объект-коллекция с кастомным типом. Проблема в том, что при апдейте, не срабатывает **convertToDatabaseValue**.
Как я понял, доктрина не понимает, что объект-коллекция изменился.

```
class Record
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="ContentContext_RecordTranslationCollection")
     * @var RecordTranslationCollection
     */
    private $translations;

...
    public function __construct   ( )
    {
        $this->translations = new RecordTranslationCollection();
    }
....
    /**
     * @param RecordTranslation $translation
     */
    public function addTranslation(RecordTranslation $translation): void
    {
        /** @var RecordTranslation $translation */
        foreach ($this->translations as $currentTranslation) {
            if ($currentTranslation->getLocale() === $translation->getLocale()) {
                $this->translations->removeElement($currentTranslation);
                break;
            }
        }
        $this->translations->add($translation);
    }
}
```

---

```
public function convertToDatabaseValue($collection, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    // при апдейте, сюда не попадаем
}


public function convertToPHPValue($json, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    $data = json_decode($json, true) ?? [];
    $collection = new RecordTranslationCollection();
    foreach ($data as $translate) {
        $collection->add($this->hydrator->hydrate($translate, RecordTranslation::class));
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

Если как-то извращаться с clone, то все работает. Есть мысли как это порешать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал ишью на гитхаб. Проблема все-же есть, пока решения достаточно костыльные:
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/7035